# Pushing other parameters in serializeArray in AJAX Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've been trying to fix my AJAX code to push extra data but I always get this error: `POST http://localhost/forexcargo_dev/partners/invoice/update net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Here's my code full AJAX code:

```
    // new addons
    var edit_new_addons = [];
    var edit_new_addon_amnts = $('#form_create_invoice table.order-tbl tbody tr.edit_new_charges_per_box');
    $.each(edit_new_addon_amnts,function(){
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); //edit_new_charges_per_box
        var addon_cat = $(this).find('select.edit_add_other_addons option:selected').text();
        var addon_cat_id = $(this).find('select.edit_add_other_addons option:selected').val();
        var addon_amnt = $(this).find('input.edit-add-addon-amount').val();
        
        if (addon_cat.length > 0 ){
            edit_new_addons.push({'category':addon_cat, 'category_id': addon_cat_id, 'amount':addon_amnt, 'order_id':$tr.data('order_id')});
        }  
    });
    
    //existing addons
    var edit_existing_addons = [];
    var edit_existing_addon_amnts = $('#form_create_invoice table.order-tbl tbody.edit_items tr.edit_charges_per_box');
    $.each(edit_existing_addon_amnts,function(){
        var addon_cat = $(this).find('select.edit_other_addons option:selected').text();
        var addon_cat_id = $(this).find('select.edit_other_addons option:selected').data('id');
        var addon_amnt = $(this).find('input.edit-addon-amount').val();
        
        if (addon_cat.length > 0 ){
            edit_existing_addons.push( {'category':addon_cat, 'category_id': addon_cat_id, 'amount':addon_amnt, 'order_id':$(this).data('order_id')} );
            
        }  
    });
    info_ajaxAnim_show(true,'Loading...');
    var edit_invoice_data = $('#form_create_invoice').serializeArray();
    edit_invoice_data.push({name: 'invoice_date', value: $('input#edit-inv_date').val()});
    edit_invoice_data.push({name: 'addons', value: edit_new_addons});
    edit_invoice_data.push({name: 'delete_addons', value: remove_addon_id});
    edit_invoice_data.push({name: 'existing_addons', value: edit_existing_addons});
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        "url": window.base_url+'partners/invoice/update', 
        data: $.param(edit_invoice_data),//{'addons':edit_new_addons, 'delete_addons':remove_addon_id, 'existing_addons':edit_existing_addons},
        dataType : 'JSON',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            info_ajaxAnim_show(false);
            var alert_type = '';
            if(response.success == true){
                alert_type = 'info';
            } else {
                alert_type = 'warning';
            }
            $('#show_invoice_modal').modal('hide');
            $('div.alert_invoice_holder').html('<div class="alert alert-' + alert_type + ' alert-dismissible text-left" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' + response.message + response.email_msg + '</div>');
            tblinvbu.ajax.reload();
        },
        error: function (MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("There was an error: " + errorThrown);  
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the part that's giving the error:

```
    edit_invoice_data.push({name: 'addons', value: edit_new_addons});
    edit_invoice_data.push({name: 'delete_addons', value: remove_addon_id});
    edit_invoice_data.push({name: 'existing_addons', value: edit_existing_addons});
```

**UPDATE:**
I narrowed down my code and did some test again. The error occurs when I change the amounts under the `existing_addons`. But when I re-select the dropdown beside it, it's working.

I already tried checking `edit_invoice_data` in `console.log()` but I don't see any issues with it. I also tried creating a separate AJAX request for them but the result is still the same. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Your `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` is json did you tried using `JSON.stringify(edit_invoice_data)` ?

Comment: @Swati I tried. It's still the same.